# Finding a proper limiting bound

Tags: calculus, limits

I encountered a situation that a function $f(x)$ with following bounds: Given $x_0 > -1 $ (a given constant) and $x > x_0$. 
$$\ln \frac{{1 + {x_0}}}{{1 + x}} < f(x) < \frac{{1 + x}}{{1 + {x_0}}} - 1$$
I was wondering if I let $x  \downarrow x_0$, can I conclude $f(x) \to 0$?.
I know if both left-hand side and right hand side have equality sign, then I'm able to conclude $f(x) \to 0$ but now the both sides are (strict) inequality which makes me confuses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $a < b$, then $a \le b$. So what you have is sufficient to give you what you need (the conditions of squeeze theorem).